# The sum over the elements of a multiplicative subgroup of a field is always zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, group-theory, convergence-divergence, field-theory

Let $G \leqslant K^{\times}$ be a multiplicative subgroup of the group of units of a field $K$.  Then $\sum_{g \in G} g = 0$ necessarily.

But, how can we prove that $\sum_{g \in G} g$ is always an element of $K$?  For instance take $\Bbb{C}^{\times}$, the multiplicative complex numbers.  Then there are numerous ways of dividing the punctured plane into two subsets $A, B$ such that $B = -A$ elementwise, and so $\sum \Bbb{C}^{\times} = A + B = 0$ necessarily.

Comment: The sum is in $K$ since it’s a sum of elements in $K$ and $K$ is closed under addition (since it’s a field).

Comment: Presumably there is supposed to be an assumption that $G$ is finite; otherwise the sum is meaningless.

Comment: @EricWofsey I make no assumption.  Specifically I'm looking at infinite subgroups of $\Bbb{C}^{\times}$.

Comment: The proof is confusing to me since it appears that you replace $0$ by the sum of interest in the third step (which you assume is not zero).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Okay, I've deleted that proof, it was totally incorrect.

Comment: To prove a similar statement when $G$ is finite, but not trivial, multiply the sum of the elements of $G$ by a nonidentity element of $G$.  If the sum is $u$ and the nonidentity element is $g$, you get $u=gu$, which is not possible.

Comment: @MichaelBurr specifically, I'm interested in the infinite case.

Comment: @AbstractAlgebraLearner What about a case like $\Bbb{F}_2(x)$, the field of rational functions with coefficients in $\Bbb{F}_2$? This is an infinite field but the sum of the inverses doesn't converge to anything.

Comment: Could you explain how you intend to evaluate $\sum_{z\in\mathbb{C}^\times}z$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't even true, not at least with some added restrictions. For example, take $K = \mathbb{F}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the field of two elements. The only unit is $1$, and so there is exactly one multiplicative subgroup. But $1 \ne 0$.

Comment: The statement is true if $G$ is finite and it has more than one element.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that $G$ is finite, then, since each element of $g$ is also an element of $K$ and since $(K,+)$ is a group. The sum of all elements of $G$ also belongs to $K$.

If $G$ is an infinite set, then the statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: $G$ may not be finite

Comment: Then the statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why doesn't the statement make sense?  Surely we can come up with some infinite sum that's over a group

Comment: There is no general concept of infinite sum on groups.

Comment: An set requires a topology (at minimum) to discuss convergence of infinite sums.